# Storyboard preview does not show different phone sizes in XCode 6

Tags: xcode, xcode6, interface-builder, preview

I just added a storyboard to be the launch image in my project. But the preview display does not show different phone sizes, it just shows a square window with the text "Development Language" beneath it. What gives?

[image]

Comment: can you show a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Adding, just for posterity, even though I solved it

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I added an OS X storyboard to my iOS project... sigh...

Comment: I disagree @lin ; the O.P. described what he did wrong and what one solution (out of many) might be.

Comment: I think that he didn't realize the answer was also from the original poster.